# How to use spark structured stream with sliding window and trigger once

Tags: spark-structured-streaming, sliding-window

I would like to use spark structured streaming to process input data and create features from it. Some features will be based on a rolling window with a stride smaller than the window, so the same events will be part of multiple window aggregations.

e.g. take the add to cart ratio over a period of a week, with a stride of one day.

The output will be stored in a delta table and I would like the checkpoint to keep track of which data needs to be processed for each window and where we left off. Since the input data is created daily per batch, we use trigger(availableNow=true) on the stream and run it daily after the input is processed. The usage of the stream allows us to not worry about backfilling in case we miss days for some reason.

I am trying to find a combination of grouping by a window and the way to write out the stream, but am not getting it right yet, here is what I have so far:

```
streaming_input_df = (
    spark
    .readStream
    .format('parquet')
    .schema(prep_schema)
    .load('/tmp/test_delta_offline_fs/preprocessed/')
)

counts = (streaming_input_df
          .withWatermark("hitDate", "0 days")
          .groupBy("prd_id", window("hitDate", "3 days", "1 day")).count()
        .filter(F.col('start_agg_window') >= '2023-01-01') #start date of data
        .filter(F.col('end_agg_window') <= '2023-01-03') #Last available date in data
)

batch_written = (counts
    .writeStream
    .trigger(availableNow=True)
    .outputMode('complete')
    .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/test_spark_stream/checkpoint_location")
    .start('/tmp/test_spark_stream/some_data/')
    )

batch_written.awaitTermination()
```

Here is some sample data to get started:

```
data = spark.createDataFrame(
    pd.DataFrame(
        {
            'hitDate': [
                '2023-01-01', '2023-01-01', '2023-01-01', '2023-01-01', '2023-01-01',
                '2023-01-02', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-02',
                '2023-01-03', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-03',
                ],
            'interaction_type': [
                'search', 'impressed', 'impressed', 'impressed', 'added_to_basket',
                'search', 'impressed', 'impressed', 'impressed', 'added_to_basket',
                'search', 'impressed', 'impressed', 'impressed', 'added_to_basket',
                ], 
            'search_query': [
                'pizza', 'pizza', 'pizza', 'pizza', 'pizza',
                'pizza', 'pizza', 'pizza', 'pizza', 'pizza',
                'pizza', 'pizza', 'pizza', 'pizza', 'pizza',
                ],
            'prd_id': [
                None, '001', '002', '003', '001', 
                None, '001', '002', '003', '002', 
                None, '001', '002', '003', '001', 
            ],
        }
    )
)

data = data.withColumn('hitDate', F.col('hitDate').cast('timestamp'))

(data
 .write
 .partitionBy("hitDate")
 .parquet('/tmp/test_delta_offline_fs/preprocessed/')
)
```

Then after triggering the stream, add another batch..

```
data = spark.createDataFrame(
    pd.DataFrame(
        {
            'hitDate': [
                '2023-01-04', '2023-01-04', '2023-01-04', '2023-01-04', '2023-01-04',
                '2023-01-05', '2023-01-05', '2023-01-05', '2023-01-05', '2023-01-05',
                '2023-01-06', '2023-01-06', '2023-01-06', '2023-01-06', '2023-01-06',
                ],
            'interaction_type': [
                'search', 'impressed', 'impressed', 'impressed', 'added_to_basket',
                'search', 'impressed', 'impressed', 'impressed', 'added_to_basket',
                'search', 'impressed', 'impressed', 'impressed', 'added_to_basket',
                ], 
            'search_query': [
                'pizza', 'pizza', 'pizza', 'pizza', 'pizza',
                'pizza', 'pizza', 'pizza', 'pizza', 'pizza',
                'pizza', 'pizza', 'pizza', 'pizza', 'pizza',
                ],
            'prd_id': [
                None, '001', '002', '003', '002', 
                None, '001', '002', '003', '002', 
                None, '001', '002', '003', '003', 
            ],
        }
    )
)

data = data.withColumn('hitDate', F.col('hitDate').cast('timestamp'))

(data
 .write
 .mode('append')
 .partitionBy("hitDate")
 .parquet('/tmp/test_delta_offline_fs/preprocessed/')
)
```

Currently, I get all the windows that I want, but for the window from 2nd to 4th of Jan, it just processes the 4th of Jan, since the rest of the data has already been processed by the checkpoint, and it does not save that it will need the same data again for a later window in a later trigger. Please advise.